# Stochastic Processes ($F_n$ measurable)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, martingales, measurable-functions

My lecture notes tell me that if $X_n$ is $F_n$ measurable then $X_n \in F_n$ for all n.

However, I do not understand how this can be the case. How can a random variable be a member of $F_n$ (which is a set of subsets of the sample space).

Appreciate any help

Comment: Presumably it is a shorthand to save writing on blackboard.

Comment: $F_n$ is not a subset of the sample space but a sigma algebra. And $X_n \in F_n$ is just a notation for the statement that $X_n$ is measurable w.r.t. $F_n$.

Comment: Ok, I see. So $\in$ has nothing to do with set notation in this context, but is just shorthand, correct? Is that a common notation used by others?

Comment: Also, the reason I was confused was because he also wrote $X_n \in F_n \Rightarrow -X_n \in F_n$. Does this just mean that the negative of the random variable is also $F_n$ measurable if the random variable itself is $F_n$ measurable?

Comment: Yes, exactly...